# Functions called on

Tags: php, function

Do functions parse the code when they are called or are they loaded even if the function isn't be called? Sorry if it seems like a newbie question, I'm just curious about this.

Thank you

Comment: What is "process their codes" supposed to mean?

Comment: The PHP interpreter compiles everything to bytecode, but a function's bytecode will _not_ be executed until that function is called

Comment: Yes sorry i meant parsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not "process their code" until they are called. For example:

```
function my_function() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

The above will not execute until you call it:

```
echo my_function();
```

With that said, the code in your function still needs to be valid or it will cause errors.

You may want to read the [**User-defined functions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) or [**W3 Schools PHP Functions**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp).

> To keep the script from being executed when the page loads, you can
>   put it into a function. A function will be executed by a call to the function.

Comment: Please, why spoil an answer with a recommendation to read w3fools

Comment: @MarkBaker - Instead of slagging off that web site why not produce a better one? Perhaps that is something that you cannot do?

Comment: @Ed - There's a lot of things I can't do, either because I don't have the ability or the time (or even both); but while there's no factual errors on that particular page of w3schools, there are too many other pages there with bad errors and disinformation... and for any new developers who're recommended that site, they won't necessarily know what is good or bad on other pages

Comment: @MarkBaker - It is better than nothing. I concur that it is not perfect but it is better than what you and I have produced.

Comment: Specifically for functions, http://www.brandonsavage.net/how-to-write-a-function-in-php/ might be better, especially as it does give a big warning at the top of the page about how it could be out of date... but I think it would probably have been better simply to provide the PHP docs link on user-defined functions in this answer

Answer (score 1):

All code in a PHP file is parsed and converted to PHP bytecode before any of it is run.

For instance, a PHP file with a syntax error anywhere in it will fail to run at all, even if the syntax error isn't anywhere near the part that is being run.